# Dual Boot (Ubuntu and Windows 7) on a RAID SSD's with UEFI

Tags: installation, windows-7, raid, uefi

I recently bought an Sony Vaio SVS13A1V9EB, which has a **RAID** between two 64 GB SSDs and a Hybrid-graphics.

(Major Issue)
I want to have **Windows 7** (It is preinstalled) and **Ubuntu** on this notebook i.e. on the RAID Drive. In **UEFI** boot mode, the Ubuntu installation fails to start with both Alternate- and Live-CD, throwing an Kernel Panic error.

Does anyone have suggestions?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

A kernel panic is unlikely to be caused by your partitioning. It's more likely a kernel bug or hardware incompatibility. The two easiest solutions are likely to be:

- Return the computer and buy something else in its place.
- Switch to another distribution.

Also, it appears that your computer is booting in UEFI mode and using GPT, which means that there's no 4-primary-partition limit as there is with older computers that boot in BIOS mode and use MBR partitioning. Thus, there's no point to deleting those two partitions except to reclaim the space they consume, which you haven't specified as an issue.

Comment: Actually, to reclaim the space was my only issue adressed by the minor issue question, which I removed. I was not sure, if I could need these OEM & Recovery partitions some day.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Rod, but what do you have in mind by switching to another distribution? Lets assume, its hardware incompatibility; may this not be solved somehow?

Comment: Distributions frequently vary in the specific kernel versions they deliver and in how they're configured. Therefore, distributions often vary in how they handle very new hardware; sometimes one will work when another one fails. These issues tend to fade with time -- a year from now, chances are all distributions will work equally well with your hardware. Right now, though, it's possible that something else will work better than Ubuntu. Also, I just noticed a "12.04" tag on your question. If you're using Ubuntu 12.04, consider trying 12.10 instead, for similar reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You will setup ubuntu live **usb** and you will update it kernel to newest one (MUST ANOTHER PC). then you can try install it  . it will work